# How to make this accordion expanded by default

Tags: html, css

I have this accordion on my site, how can I make the first block expanded by default?

http://bit.ly/1MOXoKC (CodePen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-expanded" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
```

The class of `is-expanded` instead of `is-collapsed` will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change this:

```
<dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
```

To:

```
<dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-expanded animateIn" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
```

Add `animateIn` class to maintain correct animation.

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epMLeZ)